# push into every element of an multidimentional array

Tags: php, codeigniter, multidimensional-array, array-merge, array-push

Sorry for being novice. i have a multidimensional array as under

```
array(3){
    [0] = array(2){
        [type]=>car,
        [model]=> mazda
    }
    [1]= array(2){
        [type]=>car,
        [model]=> lexus
    }
    [3]= array(2){
        [type]=>car,
        [model]=> lexus
    }
}
```

Now I want to loop through every type in this array and fetch result i.e. car company link from the database and want to push into this existing array. end result should look like

```
array(3){
    [0] = array(3){
        [type]=>car,
        [model]=> mazda,
        [link]=> http://mazda.com
    }
    [1]= array(3){
        [type]=>car,
        [model]=> lexus
        [link]=> http://lexus.com
    }
    [3]= array(3){
        [type]=>car,
        [model]=> rangerover
        [link]=> http://rangerover.com
    }
}
```

I can easily loop through this array and fetch result but I don’t know how to push this new result back into this array.

please help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the websites in the database, it might be the best idea to get all the data combined using a JOIN. Like this:

```
(pseudo code)
SELECT c.type,c.model,w.link 
FROM cars AS c
JOIN website AS w
ON c.id = w.car_id
```

If not, you must have some relation in your database to know for example that mazda is related to www.mazda.com (etc.). Then fetch all that data from the database, iterate through your array using the for loop and set something like this:

```
for ($i=0; $i<count($origArray); $i++) {
    $origArray[i]['link'] = $dbArray['carName']; // or whatever the relation you have - name, id, etc...
}
```

Assuming that the $dbArray looks like this:

```
'mazda' => 'http://mazda.com',
'rangerover' => 'http://rangerover.com',
etc...
```